# Wildfly Docker Container Live Migration with CRIU fails

Tags: docker, wildfly, restore, checkpoint

I'm trying to live migrate a wildfly docker container to another host like described [here](https://circleci.com/blog/checkpoint-and-restore-docker-container-with-criu/). The np-example runs very well.

This is my container

```
docker run -itd -p 8081:8080 -v /tmp/docker/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/:rw --name=mywildfly jboss/wildfly
```

But when I try to checkpoint it, I get this error

```
docker checkpoint mywildfly
Error response from daemon: Cannot checkpoint container mywildfly: criu failed: type NOTIFY errno 0
Error: failed to checkpoint one or more containers
```

Even a suspended wildfly server and a container without port forwarding and volume sharing cannot be checkpointed.

```
 docker run --name=wildfly -itd jboss/wildfly
```

Can anyone tell me how to find a log file to specify the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't checkpoint a container which is run with the -t option as stated at the end of the documentation here:

https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md